# Can Naive Bayes fit non-linear decision boundaries?

Tags: naive-bayes

I am confused about Naive Bayes. Some sources e.g. [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_naive_bayes_1.html) suggest only linear decision boundaries can be fit. Others [here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468469/logistic-regression-and-naive-bayes-for-this-dataset) or [here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142215/how-is-naive-bayes-a-linear-classifier) say or [just suspect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136538/is-the-naive-bayes-family-of-classifiers-linear) they can be non-linear. What is true? Are both suppositions based on different assumptions, perhaps?

Specifically the latter two source says that they can be linear if distributions are taken from the exponential family but this makes naive Bayes not per-se linear.

Comment: Related: [Can naive Bayes model this type of (approx. circular) decision boundary?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/243359/12359)